# MetaStorm Ework and SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

Has anyone had any experience working with MetaStorm Ework web parts in SharePoint 2007?

I've been asked to have a look at this and would be interested to know your thoughts on the best way to approach this.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer, but you can probably find an answer on our Metastorm BPM Forums, or post the question there and you can get a quick response:

http://metastorm.processmapping.com.au/

Comment: Processmapping is a great resource for Metastorm BPM questions.